# PHP RegEx match string with random number at end

Tags: php, regex

Currently learning PHP with RegEx and I want to extract the DAX value from a website.

Got the website source with `file_get_contents` and then cleaned up the tags with `strip_tags`.


The block that contains the string i want is this one:
`Dax5.502-2,4%`

but i just need the value `5.502`

The regex code I have so far is `'/@Dax\d.\d\d\d[+-]\d,\d[%]$/'`

But it doesnt work. can anyone tell me how to do this correctly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"/Dax(.*)-/"
```

your result will be the number

Comment: Got it with a combination of yours and Kolinks answers :). /Dax([0-9].[0-9]{3})-/ Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`/^Dax([0-9].[0-9]{3})/`

With that (which is all you need), your result will be the number.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) but doesn't work yet. what about the -2,4% at the end of the line? There is no space between them.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a regular expression to parse the formatted string, [`sscanf`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/sscanf) looks like a more fitting way to parse the *float* value ([Demo](http://codepad.org/otHBHnfZ)):

```
$str = 'Dax5.502-2,4%';

sscanf($str, 'Dax%f', $value);

echo $value; # 5.502
```